# build a perfect maze recursively in python

Tags: python, recursion, path-finding, maze

I have this project to build a perfect maze recursively by using python. I have a MyStack class which creates a stack to track the path that I go through. And a Cell class which represent each square within the maze and store some information. I think I complete the code but IDLE gives me some error that I couldn't figure out. Here is the code.

```
from random import *
from graphics import *

class MyStack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.S = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.S.insert(0, item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.S.pop(0)

    def isEmpty(self):
        return True if len(self.S) == 0 else False

    def size(self):
        return len(self.S)

class Maze:
    def __init__(self, N):

        self.size = N
        self.maze = [[i for i in range(N + 2)] for i in range(N + 2)]

        for r in range(self.size + 2):
            for c in range(self.size + 2):
                self.maze[r][c] = Cell()

    def walk(self, s, x, y):

        neighboor = [(x + 1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1)]

        if s.size() == self.size**2: return

        else:
            new = choice(neighboor)

            while self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].getVisit():

                while new[0] < 1 or new[1] > self.size:

                    new = choice(neighboor)

                if neighboor != []: new = choice(neighboor.remove(new))
                else:
                    temp = s.pop(s)
                    x, y = temp[0], temp[1]
                    self.walk(s, x, y)

            if new == neighboor[0]:
                self.maze[x][y].changeNorth()
                self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].changeSouth()
            elif new == neighboor[1]:
                self.maze[x][y].changeSouth()
                self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].changeNorth()
            elif new == neighboor[2]:
                self.maze[x][y].changeEast()
                self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].changeWest()
            elif new == neighboor[3]:
                self.maze[x][y].changeWest()
                self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].changeEast()


            s.push(new)

            self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])

    def search(self):
        startX, startY = randint(1, self.size), randint(1, self.size)

        s = MyStack()

        temp = (startX, startY)

        s.push(temp)

        self.maze[startX][startY].changeVisit()

        self.walk(s, startX, startY)

    def draw(self):

        win = GraphWin()

        startXY = Point(27, 27)
        start = Circle(startXY, 5)
        start.setOutline('orange')
        start.setFill('orange')
        start.draw(win)

        x, y = 20, 20


        for r in range(1, self.size + 1):
            for c in range(1, self.size + 1):
                if self.maze[r][c].getNorth():
                    unit = Line(Point(x, y), Point(x + 15, y))
                    unit.draw(win)

                x, y = x + 15, y

            x, y = 20, y + 15

        x, y = 20, 20
        for c in range(1, self.size + 1):
            for r in range(1, self.size + 1):
                if self.maze[r][c].getWest():
                    #print(self.maze[r][c].getWest())
                    unit = Line(Point(x, y), Point(x, y + 15))
                    unit.draw(win)

                x, y = x, y + 15

            x, y = x + 15, 20

        x, y = 20, self.size * 15 + 20
        for c in range(1, self.size + 1):
            if self.maze[self.size][c].getSouth():
                unit = Line(Point(x, y), Point(x + 15, y))
                unit.draw(win)
            x, y = x + 15, y

        x, y = self.size * 15 + 20, 20
        for r in range(1, self.size + 1):
            if self.maze[self.size][c].getEast():
                unit = Line(Point(x, y), Point(x, y + 15))
                unit.draw(win)
            x, y = x, y + 15

class Cell:
    def __init__(self):
        #self.x = x
        #self.y = y
        self.north = True
        self.south = True
        self.east = True
        self.west = True
        self.visit = False

    def changeVisit(self):
        self.visit = True

    def changeNorth(self):
        self.north = False

    def changeSouth(self):
        self.south = False

    def changeEast(self):
        self.east = False

    def changeWest(self):
        self.west = False

    def getVisit(self):
        return self.visit

    def getNorth(self):
        return self.north

    def getSouth(self):
        return self.south

    def getEast(self):
        return self.east

    def getWest(self):
        return self.west
```

Here is the Error I got:

```
>>> a = Maze(5)
>>> a.search()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    a.search()
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 91, in search
    self.walk(s, startX, startY)
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 76, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 48, in walk
    while self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].getVisit():
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm new to programming, any help would be appreciate. Thank you~

After fix the previous one, I got an error for the line

```
    if len(neighboor) != 0: new = choice(neighboor.remove(new))
```

The error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    a.search()
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 88, in search
    self.walk(s, startX, startY)
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 73, in walk
    self.walk(s, new[0], new[1])
  File "C:\Users\Serena\Desktop\XAproject\Stack.py", line 52, in walk
    if len(neighboor) != 0: new = choice(neighboor.remove(new))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\random.py", line 253, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

But I define 'neighboor' as a list, it should has a len()

Thank you so much for help! plzplz~

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code, please ensure that the indentation of the question matches the indentation of your code.

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` have you tried searching online for that error message? It tells you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not ensuring that the steps in your walk are valid.

The way you have it currently, `walk` could pick a `neighboor` that is out of the bounds of the maze.  For example, if a maze is 5x5, attempting to access `maze[5][?]` or `maze[?][5]` will result in an `IndexError` like you get.

To fix this, you could define an `is_valid` method for your maze class, e.g.:

```
def is_valid(self, x, y):
    return (0 <= x < self.size) and (0 <= y < self.size)
```

Then, you when you pick a `neighboor`, you ensure it's valid:

```
#...
else:
    new = choice(neighboor)
    while self.is_valid(new[0], new[1]) == False:
        new = choice(neighboor)

    while self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].getVisit():
#...
```

This snippet picks a `neighboor`, then, if it's not valid, regenerates `new` until it finds a valid one.

But this loop would be better written as:

```
#...
else:
    while True:
        new = choice(neighboor)
        if self.is_valid(new[0], new[1]): break

    while self.maze[new[0]][new[1]].getVisit():
#...
```

There are more problems with your code, however, as you'll eventually see, but this will get you past this specific one.

Comment: @SerenaQi, I saw that there would be more errors.  If you can't figure what is going on, try searching for the error on here, and if you can't figure it out, feel free to post another question.  If possible though, try to condense your question down to the smallest version necessary to reproduce your error.  [This may help with that](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thx, first time post a question here☺️