# check validation for input for perfect maze

Tags: python, recursion, path-finding, maze

I'm working on a project to build a perfect maze. 
I have a class Maze and a class Cell which represents each square in a maze. In my Cell class, I have four Boolean variable(north, south, east, west) to represent whether there is a wall at north or south.. of cell. There is also a boolean variable named visit to check if the cell has been visited. Here is my code for the **init**() for Cell class.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.north = True
    self.south = True
    self.east = True
    self.west = True
    self.visit = False
```

And for the Maze class, I have self.maze(a bunch of Cell) and the self.size = N(build a N*N maze).
Here is the **init**() for class Maze:

```
def __init__(self, N):

    self.size = N
    self.maze = [[i for i in range(N + 2)] for i in range(N + 2)]

    for r in range(self.size + 2):
        for c in range(self.size + 2):
            self.maze[r][c] = Cell()
```

While I'm updating the index of maze, I wrote two function to check whether the newX and newY is in the range of 1 <= x <= self.size and 1 <= y <= self.size, also whether the cell has been visited.
Here is the code:

```
def in_range(self, x, y):

    if 1 <= x <= self.size and 1 <= y <= self.size:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_valid(self, x, y):

    if not self.maze[x][y].getVisit() and self.in_range(x,y):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

After all this, I wrote the main structure:

```
def walk(self, s, x, y):

    neighbor = [(x + 1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1)]


    if s.size() == self.size**2: return

    else:

        while True:
            new = choice(neighbor)#choice() is import from random
            #print(self.is_valid(new[0], new[1]))
            if self.is_valid(new[0], new[1]):break
            else:
                if len(neighbor) != 0:
                    neighbor.remove(new)
                    new = choice(neighbor)
                else:
                    temp = s.pop(s)
                    self.walk(s, temp[0], temp[1])

                break
    print(new)
```

However, running my code stills give me index that is not between 1 and self.size. I couldn't figure out why, I think my checking algorithm works fine.
Here is what I got:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART 

================================
>>> 
>>> a = Maze(5)
>>> a.search()
1 2
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(2, 4)
(1, 4)
(2, 4)
(2, 5)
(3, 5)
(4, 5)
(4, 4)
(4, 3)
(3, 3)
(3, 2)
(2, 2)
(2, 1)
(1, 1)
(0, 1)
(-1, 1)
(0, 1)
(1, 1)
(0, 1)
(-1, 1)
(-1, 2)
(-1, 1)
(0, 1)
```

Can someone help me out? plz, really appreciate!

Comment: Is it [build-a-perfect-maze](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450400/build-a-perfect-maze-recursively-in-python) week again?

Comment: Why do you use `range(N + 2)` everywhere? That will create an (N+1)x(N+1) maze. Just create a [numpy.array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) of Cell.

Comment: Glad to help.  Could you please post your class code for the Maze and the Cell?

Comment: And what is `if s.size() == self.size**2: return` checking for? How is that a termination condition? Unless you're trying to randomly discover paths of length N**2 (but they're not necessarily loops or complete traversals).

Comment: Coz the Prof said to build a N+2 maze to avoid some tedious problem. To be frankly, I don't know the reason either.

Comment: class MyStack:

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.s.insert(0, item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.s.pop(0)

    def isEmpty(self):
        return True if len(self.s) == 0 else False

    def size(self):
        return len(self.s).<br/>I have this class MyStack, which is `s` represents for. Stack keeps track what cell(x, y) I've been visited and `s.size()` return the length of the stack. If it equals to n**2, then I know I visited all the cell in maze, so I can terminate the recursion.

Comment: @smci I try to formatting my comment. But looks like the code part didn't work out. So sorry for the mess.

Answer (score 0):

In Python [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) starts with 0 if you don't specify another start position. Thus, when you initialize your maze, you have cells in `(0, *)` and `(*, 0)`:

```
for r in range(self.size + 2):
    for c in range(self.size + 2):
        self.maze[r][c] = Cell()
```

When you compute your neighbors you don't check that you don't get out:

```
neighbor = [(x + 1, y), (x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x, y - 1)]
```

And it's only after having assigned `new` to such a coordinates that you check it is valid. But then, if it is *not* valid and there is no neighbors, you're calling `walk` again. You should try to check for `in_range` independently of `visit`.

Also your loop can only run once because either `new` is valid and you break out of the loop or it is not valid and you break out of the loop.

Finally, you forgot to give us the `search` function and what `s` is (and `s.pop(s)` looks funny as usually the argument of `pop` is an index, not the sequence again).

Answer (score 0):

You could have found this by looking closely at `walk()`, or splattering it with `print` statements to trace things.
Things are going wrong at the extremities of your grid (when either x or y == 0 or N-1). Unless you're allowing wraparound, I assume your grid initialization puts walls on the north of the grid(y==0), south, east and west. 
By the way, your grid has two unnecessary rows and columns: if you want N cells, numbered O..(N-1), then use `range(N)`, not `range(N+2)`, Or else use `range(1,N+1)`. (Do you pad any unneeded cells with valid==False?)

Anyway, `walk()` first picks a random neighbor cell and breaks out of the while-loop if it is a valid cell. But if it isn't, it cheerfully picks **any remaining neighbor cell** (regardless whether valid) and soldiers on. That's your bug. Always test validity.
If it has run out of valid neighbor cells, it backtracks by doing `s.pop(s)`. `s.pop(s)` also looks like a bug. Why not `s.pop()`? 
Btw, call the variable `path` instead of `s`.

Also, this is only checking the coords for validity; you never actually check if you've visited that cell before, so there's no end condition to your recursive backtracking; you could very easily go in loops.

You could help yourself a lot if you refactored `walk()` into using a separate generator `get_random_valid_neighbor()` which returns randomly-chosen neighbors already tested as valid (and `None` when you run out of neighbors).

```
def walk(self, s, x, y):

...
      while True:
            new = choice(neighbor)
            if self.is_valid(new[0], new[1]):break # tested for validity
            else:
                if len(neighbor) != 0:
                    neighbor.remove(new)
                    new = choice(neighbor) # BUG: never tested for validity
                ...
```